# Add key value pair to helm values.yaml file

Tags: kubernetes-helm, react-helmet

I have a use case to write a randomly generated password back to `values.yaml` file.

I don't want to use `install` or `upgrade` command, having a hard time reading through documentation.

Apart from going through the helm way, I tried updating `values.yaml` file through `yq` command but it is removing the comments in the file.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Helm can't write back local files at all, but I can imagine a couple of ways to do this from the shell.  Write a new YAML (or JSON) file and pass it with `helm install -f` instead of trying to edit the chart's `values.yaml` in place.

Comment: The use case won't allow creating a new YAML (or JSON) file as the number of files will increase and make things complex. I tried `yq` which has an open bug where it removes comments in the YAML file. I'm trying to write key value pair back to `values.yaml` with python now.

Comment: Can you share some ways to do it from shell commands directly?